# Perl regex with capture groups not working

Tags: regex, perl

I have the following file:

```
/Users/x/-acite _1660475490N.html
/Users/x/-acite _1660464772N.html
/Users/x/-acite _1660464242N.html
/Users/x/-acite _1660463321N.html
/Users/x/-acite _1660421444N.html
/Users/x/-acite _1612414441N.html

/Users/x/fix _1660399672N.html
/Users/x/fix _1660398829N.html

/Users/x/water witching _1660460617N.html
/Users/x/water witching _1660388149N.html
/Users/x/water witching _1632222441N.html
/Users/x/water witching _1660003224N.html
```

I need

```
/Users/x/-acite _1660475490N.html
/Users/x/fix _1660399672N.html
/Users/x/water witching _1660460617N.html
```

I use the following perl regex:

```
find . -type f -exec perl -pi -w -e 's/(.*)(\R)(.*)(\R)/$1$2/' \{\} \;
```

or

```
find . -type f -exec perl -pi -w -e 's/(.*?)(\R)(.*?)(\R)/$1$2/g;' \{\} \;
```

Why are these not working?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You are

- not slurping the whole file to a single string and
- only replacing the first occurrence
- and you do not need so many groups, you just need one since you want to keep one part of a match.

You need

```perl
find . -type f -exec perl -0777 -i -pe 's/^(.+)(?:\R.+)*\n/$1/gm' \{\} \;
```

Here,

- `-0777` slurps the file
- `^` - start of a line (due to `m` flag)
- `(.+)` - matches a non-empty line
- `(?:\R.+)*`  - zero or more sequences of a line break and a non-empty line
- `\n` - matches a newline

Comment: I see. What if there are more than one lines for e.g. `-acite` or `water witching`? (see the edit above)

Comment: @simoneante So, you just need to keep the first one?

Comment: Right. Just the first one.

Answer (score 3):

Also, you could read in `paragraph` mode, (`-00`), and match and print the first line of each 'paragraph'.

```
C:\Old_Data\perlp>perl -00 -ne "print /(.+\n)/" test01.txt
/Users/x/-acite _1660475490N.html
/Users/x/fix _1660399672N.html
/Users/x/water witching _1660460617N.html
```

Note that this was run on a PC and uses the double quote (") in the statement. On a *nix machine, would use a single quote (').